# Can't receive notification RS485/UART/RS232

Tags: flutter, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, uart

I'm building flutter application for a battery that have a BMS (Bluetooth Smart). This application must display information using the BMS. But I can't communicate with it. I can connect to the battery using library from flutter. After many research and with nRF Connect (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=fr&gl=US),  I understand that I have to write to the TX and activate the notify (RX) to get the information. But I don't know what value I have to write to activate the notification.

I know the protocol is : RS485/UART/RS232 Protocol

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the battery? Does it come with an official app?

Comment: They give me this.
https://www.sendspace.com/file/hmi4ji